# what is inside weak-update folder?

Tags: centos, drivers, upgrade, kernel-modules, rpm

First, installed a driver package to OS (ex: CentOS ) -- foo_1.0.rpm
Second, install the same driver but different version -- foo_2.0.rpm by

```
rpm -ivh --force foo_2.0.rpm
```

It seems an extra folder called /weak_update/ was created @ /usr/lib/modules/3.xxxx/weak-updates/

The content of /weak-updates/ seems to be the same content of foo_1.0.

what is this /weak-updates/ usage ?